# Problema com DatePicker no Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Estou com um problema na hora de setar o `state` do `DatePicker` no Flutter.

O mesmo me retorna o erro:

> Another exception was thrown: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

Código:

```js
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterPage createState() => _RegisterPage();
}

class _RegisterPage extends State<RegisterPage> {
  DateTime data;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  Future<Null> _nascimento(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime selecionado = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: data == null ? DateTime.now() : data,
      firstDate: DateTime(1950),
      lastDate: DateTime.now()
    );

    if(selecionado != null && selecionado != data) {
      print('Data:  ${selecionado.toString()}');
   
      setState(() {
        data = selecionado;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipPath(
              clipper: Topo(),
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 250,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/pngs/recycle.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 160,
              height: 160,
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -140.0, 0.0),
              child: Material(
                elevation: 5.0,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                // color: Colors.white,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/jpgs/no_avatar.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -100.0, 0.0),
              child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                          child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            elevation: 5.0,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.perm_identity,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    size: 26,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Nome',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter some text';
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                          child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            elevation: 5.0,
                            child: TextField(
                              onTap: () => _nascimento(context),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.date_range,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    size: 26,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                labelText: '${data.toString()}',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                          child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            elevation: 5.0,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.email,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    size: 26,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Email',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter some text';
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                          child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            elevation: 5.0,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.lock,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    size: 26,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Senha',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter some text';
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height: 50,
                              child: FlatButton(
                                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.green,
                                child: Text(
                                  "Cadastrar",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Topo extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 100);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height - 100);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Após alterar a data recebo o seguinte erro:

> I/flutter ( 4615): Data:  2019-07-09 00:00:00.000
>   I/flutter ( 4615): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 4615): The following assertion was thrown building
>   I/flutter ( 4615): RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#605fc](state:
>   I/flutter ( 4615): RawGestureDetectorState#6184a(gestures: [vertical drag], behavior: opaque)):
>   I/flutter ( 4615): Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
>   I/flutter ( 4615):
>   I/flutter ( 4615): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
>   I/flutter ( 4615): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
>   I/flutter ( 4615): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
>   I/flutter ( 4615):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
>   I/flutter ( 4615):
>   I/flutter ( 4615): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #0      _RenderCustomClip.clipper= (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1171:20)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #1      ClipPath.updateRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:797:18)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #2      RenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4510:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #3      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:11)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #4      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #5      RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:32)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #6      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:17)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #12     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #14     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #16     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #18     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #19     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #20     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #24     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #25     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #26     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #28     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #30     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #32     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #38     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3796:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #39     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #40     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #41     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #42     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #44     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #45     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #46     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #47     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #48     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #49     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #50     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #51     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #52     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #53     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #54     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3796:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #55     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #56     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #57     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #58     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #60     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #61     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #62     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #63     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #64     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:32)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #65     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:17)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #66     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #67     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #68     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #69     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #70     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #71     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #72     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #73     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #74     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #75     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #76     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #77     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #78     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #79     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #80     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #81     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #82     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #83     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3796:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #84     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #85     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #86     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #87     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #88     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #89     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #90     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #91     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #92     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #93     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #94     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #95     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #96     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #97     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #98     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #99     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #100    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #101    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #102    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #103    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #104    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #105    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #106    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #107    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3750:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #108    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #109    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2278:33)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #110    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:700:20)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #111    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:286:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #112    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1012:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #113    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:952:9)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #114    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:864:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #118    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:10)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): #119    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:178:3)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
>   I/flutter ( 4615): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 4615): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 2169 pos 12: 'attached': is not true.

Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

Comment: Qual o stacktrace completo? Em que linha o erro está ocorrendo? Que tal um código completo executável para testarmos?

Comment: @JulioHenriqueBitencourt inseri o código completo na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao rodar seu código, o erro está em:

```dart
@override
bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
  return null;
}
```

Retorne `false` ou `true` ao invés de null.

Por isso a mensagem

> Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

Note que ao atualizar a data você está atualizando todo o estado do widget

```dart
if(selecionado != null && selecionado != data) {
  print('Data:  ${selecionado.toString()}');

  setState(() {
    data = selecionado;
  });
}
```

Ao atualizar o estado, o `CustomClipper` executa o método para saber se ele deve redesenhar o `Clipper`.

Comment: Julio, obrigado!!!!
Estou iniciando no mundo do dart agora, então terei alguns problemas "bobos" como esse, resolvido!